# Get the complete number when divide two fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, rounding, operation

I was trying to round some fields. When I have 59 days, I want to change it to 60.

The problem is that when I use this code, the 59 is changed to 30 because the round it is 1.

```
 select round(1.9666,0)*30, round(59/30,0)*3'
```

The result of that query is 60 for the first field and 30 for the second one. The problem is that when I've tried:

```
 select 59/30
```

The result is 1 and I need the entire answer that is 1.9666...

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

Because the number you are dividing by is an `INT` (the data type of the left side is irrelevant), SQL Server will return an `INT` as the answer.

If you want a number with a decimal place as your result, you'll need to divide by one.

Don't cast to a `FLOAT` as the answer is probably not what you want (floats are generally not accurate and are ['approximations'](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-GB%2Flibrary%2Fms173773.aspx&ei=z2w2Vcz7L4HpsAGQkIHwDw&usg=AFQjCNGywUtcLN-yU2nOxz02rKu8gHzgMQ&sig2=-Uqi7b8suYMT0x8bk1VJkw&bvm=bv.91071109,d.bGg)):

```
SELECT 59 / CAST(30 AS FLOAT) -- = 1.96666666666667
```

`CAST` the right-hand side of the division to a `DECIMAL`:

```
SELECT 59 / CAST(30 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) -- = 1.96666
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cast(59 AS FLOAT) / cast(30 AS FLOAT)
```

Because the original figures are whole numbers, SQL presumes you want a whole number output.

To ensure you get one with the decimal places, you need to first change the data type from an integer `int` to a floating point `float`.

This is what the CAST command does.

EDIT: Commenter suggests you cast to DECIMAL instead. The principle is the same, but you need to supply more arguments. To cast to a decimal use something like:

```
cast(59 as DECIMAL(18, 3))
```

The first argument (the 18) is the total number of figures you want to permit in the decimal. The second argument (the 3) is the number you want after the decimal point.

The suggestion that it's more accurate is correct - as you'll see if you run the SELECT statements in this answer one after the other. But in this particular case, it only makes a tiny difference.

Comment: Don't `CAST` to `FLOAT`, cast to `DECIMAL`. Floating point numbers are not accurate